# no module name 'celery' after migrate

Tags: python, django, celery

I have been following tutorial how to import celery and run rabbitmq to my django project. and I have been following a tutorial on youtube. I do not now what I have missed but after the part where i ran `python manage.py migrate djcelery` it gives the result of:

```
root@1095ea233e7b:/app/main# python3 manage.py migrate djcelery
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/main/actinbox/settings.py", line 6, in <module>
    import djcelery
```

this is the tutorial that I have been following:

[Django Celery Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZQtMPMeT8c)

Comment: Do you added celery in install app ?

Comment: Do you installed Celery in root or other user?

Comment: yes I installed celery in root since I am running my project in a docker container

Comment: What is your celery version? 4.0.0 had some major changes which may cause incompatibles... If you do not have celery pinned i'd recommend pinning it at < 4.0.0.
the tutorial you followed is of celery 3.0. And if you do `pip install django-celery' you install 4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, it's probably because you installed celery 4.0.0. 
the tutorial you followed uses celery 3.0.23.

If you really want to use the tutorial use `pip install django-celery==3.0.23`
this is not recommended because it's an outdated version.